# FTDI FTD2xx_NET detects unknown device. CyclePort fails

Tags: c#, winforms, serial-port, ftdi, reconnect

I want to detect a connected usb device (FT232R USB UART, Virtual com port driver). This usually worked fine, but due to an windows update my device is detected as FTDI_DEVICE_UNKNOWN. Strange behaviour is, that when I first plug in my device and then start the software, everything works fine. If I first  start the software and then plug in the device, it it not detected. I tried to use CyclePort to reconnect the device, but this fails with status FT_OTHER_ERROR. The device is detected and displayed in both cases in the windows device manager. Drivers were already updated and also installed manually.
Any ideas as to what is causing this?

Here is my code:

```
            List<string> pcdSerials = new List<string>();
            FTDI ftdi = new FTDI(); 
            UInt32 ftdiDeviceCount = 0;
            FTDI.FT_STATUS ftStatus = FTDI.FT_STATUS.FT_OK;

            ftStatus = ftdi.GetNumberOfDevices(ref ftdiDeviceCount);
            if (ftStatus != FTDI.FT_STATUS.FT_OK)
            {
                return pcdSerials;
            }
            FTDI.FT_DEVICE_INFO_NODE[] ftdiDeviceList = new FTDI.FT_DEVICE_INFO_NODE[ftdiDeviceCount];
            ftStatus = ftdi.GetDeviceList(ftdiDeviceList);
            if (ftStatus != FTDI.FT_STATUS.FT_OK)
            {
                return pcdSerials;
            }

            foreach (var info in ftdiDeviceList)
            {                    
                if (info.Type == FTDI.FT_DEVICE.FT_DEVICE_UNKNOWN)
                {
                    if (ftdiDeviceList.Count() == 1)
                    { 
                        // The effect of this function is the same as disconnecting then reconnecting the device from USB. 
                        // Possible use of this function is in situations where a fatal error has occurred and it is difficult, or not possible, to recover without unplugging and replugging the USB cable. This function can also be used after re-programming the EEPROM to force the FTDI device to read the new EEPROM contents which previously required a physical disconnect-reconnect.

                        ftStatus = ftdi.CyclePort();                         
                        if (ftStatus == FTDI.FT_STATUS.FT_OK)
                        {                                
                            // Port has been cycled. Close the handle.
                            ftStatus = ftdi.Close();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            // FT_CyclePort FAILED!
                        }                        
                        break;                            
                    }
                }                  

                if (info.Description != "FT232R USB UART")
                    continue;
                if (info.Type != FTDI.FT_DEVICE.FT_DEVICE_232R)
                    continue;
               
                pcdSerials.Add(info.SerialNumber);
            }

            return pcdSerials;
```

Answer (score 0):

This NOT an answer, but a comment. Being new to Stack overflow it wouldn't let me simply add a comment to your question, or I don;t know what I am doing. :)
I am having what sounds like the same issue. I wrote a wrapper class over 10 years ago that has worked fine until the new FTDI driver 2.12.36.1 was updated on client's computers. FTDI released driver version 2.12.36.2 on 6/17/2021 and I was hoping that it would resolve the issue but it did not.
What I have found is that calling FT_CreateDeviceInfoList does return the correct number of devices connected. Then I call FT_GetDeviceInfoDetail to obtain the device type, description, and FTDI serial number. The device type comes back as value 0x03 which is FT_Device_Unknown and the description and serial number appear to come back empty. I use the FTDI serial number to open the device by its serial number. Without a valid serial number, I cannot open the device. I have used this method as outlined as the preferred method by FTDI for years with no issues until now.
Hopefully someone else can chime in with an answer as I have a lot of customers who are unable to connect to my product with their PCs.
I am going to reach out to FTDI support to see if they can shed some light on this problem. I will post back here if I hear something back.

Comment: thanks for your post. I have no solution for the problem, so if you have any further ideas, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same problem just recently.  If you run FT_prog you can replicate this by removing the dongle and putting it back.  FT_prog takes a second or so to recognise the device again.

I put the checking code in a loop with a 1 second wait and it now finds the dongle on the second attempt reliably.